# VideoJS caption causing undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, video.js

I'm using VideoJS, the CDN hosted version works fine, but I wish to use VideoJS offline and modify the CSS so I'm hosting this myself.

I'm getting an undefined error on the videojs.js:

```
this.player.textTrackDisplay.addComponent(this);
```

I know my captions.vtt file is correct, as it works with the demo html file.  My markup:

```
<div id="mainVideoList">
        <video id="mainVideoOne" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="956" height="538" autoplay preload="auto" loop data-setup="{}">
            <source type="video/mp4" src="assets/Penguins.mp4">
            <track kind="subtitles" src="src/videojs/captions.vtt" default>
        </video>
    </div>
```

The video plays fine, but the error is thrown and no captions are shown.

Thanks.

EDIT: The error is only thrown if I set the captions to be default, and the controls to not be visible.

Comment: Why not keep using the CDN version and include your own `custom-videojs.css` file after you included the original videojs CSS? That way, you can have custom CSS and keep using the CDN. Win-win.

Comment: Because the site has to run offline with no connection to the outside world.

Comment: That makes total sense. A CDN wouldn't work then. Your question suggested it was CSS related: *but I wish to modify the CSS so I'm hosting this myself.*

Comment: Yes, I should have been more clear.

Comment: Are there any other dependancies missing? If you run your offline version with (eg) Chrome developer tools open do you get a 404 for anything VideoJS is looking for? also are you opening your page, video and captions via the same mechanism (file:// or http://) as I've seen that upset things

Comment: Nothing missing, no errors at all.  I think this could be a bug with VideoJS itself, for now I'm going to roll my own.

Comment: Can we see the rest of your JS for a little context?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Chapters functionality you are looking for does not (yet) work in videojs versions 4.x -- this is a known issue:

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/676

Older 3.x versions **did** work, however.  I've used v3.2 successfully to deliver video with chapters (even worked in IE6) -- but earlier versions of the player were neither accessible nor responsive (without a lot of extra effort).

To quickly deal with the uncaught TypeError (not having enough time to deal with this more thoroughly), I added the following band-aid:

```
if (typeof component === 'undefined') return;
```

to the function

```
vjs.Component.prototype.addChild
```

just before the line:

```
this.children_.push(component);
```

(in the non-minified version of v4.3 I'm using, this would be around line 1660).

This obviously does nothing to fix the broken Chapters functionality, but will catch the error being thrown.

I'd suggest checking this link from time to time, as there appears to (finally) be some forward movement on the issue within the past few months: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/676